# Paypal IPN POST variables randomly returning item_number or item_number1

Tags: php, html, paypal

Paypal for the last few days has randomly started returning the POST variable of item_number1 instead of item_number and the same for item_name. I've read on Paypals website that they do this when it's a cart transaction(multiple items). These are instant payments for wifi access of a single item so I'm not sure why after years of running without seeing this it has suddenly started randomly happening. In the returned data to the IPN listener I also get a "num_cart_items=1" if it has sent the "item_number1". So it is definitely thinking some transactions are shopping cart ones. Is there any way I can stop this happening?

Comment: Paypal: giving developers needless headaches for 15 years. [Use Stripe](https://stripe.com/gb).

Comment: If it means anything the user I had that caused this said they used the PayPal web site client but the flow looked different than usual and pressured them into facebook messenger integration. Dunno if it's connected. I sent PayPal a support email yesterday and got a nonsense response. I'm calling them today ill post back.

Answer (score 3):

Similar here. I temporary deal with the issue with the following:

```
if (!$_POST['item_number']) {
     $_POST['item_number']=$_POST['item_number1']; }
```

I still wonder why it randomly changes item_number to item_number1 and there was no notice or announcement for that. I had half orders passing and half not, and though that was PayPal IPN issue, not my file !

Comment: Thanks I'm doing something similar as a workaround but was hoping I could send a post variable to Paypal that would inform their system that it is not a cart transaction. I currently send `<input type="hidden" name="txn_type" value="web_accept">` and wondering if changing that to `<input type="hidden" name="txn_type" value="express_checkout">` would fix it.

Comment: Experienced the same and handled it with a similar logic.

Comment: Will that affect any other process (like recurring or so) if I change my froms from web_accept to express_checkout?

Comment: Seldimi it probably would but you could specify different txn_type for recurring payments. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/

Comment: Seems fixed as said on https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/About-Business/Massive-problem-with-IPN/td-p/1261733

Answer (score 2):

Same here. Started yesterday with random behaviour.
I'm not interested in such "shopping cart" functions so I have modified my ipn receiver to scan for the first "item_number" available.

Answer (score 1):

look for "item_number1" if "item_number" does not exist

this page referes to item_number in paypal docs
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/

this page refers to item_numberx
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/

so annoyed with paypal!
and it's so hard to reconcile with paypal as you cannot even search for a transaction by the item_number or order reference number...

Comment: I just wanted to mention, that I experienced the same problem. "item_name1" instead of "item_name" all of a sudden for several payments in the last two days. Today it's "item_name" again. I've now implemented a fallback to deal with this annoying problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that as well yesterday (13th july), today is running well. Anyway, I patched the code checking out does two variables. This might be a joke from paypal, tomorrow might be $_POST['item_number69'] :D